# How do I alter the default URL location of EasyPHP

Tags: easyphp

EasyPHPs homepage is accessed from : http://127.0.0.1/home/.
Virtual Host manager sets a local domain name to redirect to 127.0.0.1 in the hosts file.
When I navigate to 'mylocaldomain.com/home/' I get an error 'The requested URL was not found on this server.' because '/home/index.php' is used for the Admin Panel of EasyPHP.

I need to use '/home/' in my local domains, so I want to try and change the default URL that EasyPHP homepage is using.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had this problem and ran across your question. This is how you solve it:

- Access your EasyPHP Apache config file (on Windows, I right-click on the taskbar icon, go to Configuration, then click Apache)
- Look for the line `Alias /home "${path}/binaries/home"` - Mine was at line 359
- Change the first `/home` to **/something-you-won't-think-to-use-on-your-websites**
- Restart the server

That should do it